# How to mock Module with config in AngularJS with Jest?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jestjs

I have the following test Setup:

mathservice.js:

```
angular.module('mathmodule', []).config([])
.factory('mathservice', function(){

var addTwoNumbers = function(x, y){
  return x + y;
};

var multiplyTwoNumbers = function(x, y){
  return x * y;
};

return {
  addTwoNumbers,
  multiplyTwoNumbers
};
});
```

mathservice.test.js:

```
require('../../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js');
require('../../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js');
require('./mathservice.js');

describe('Math service - addTwoNumbers', function(){

  beforeEach(
    angular.mock.module('mathmodule')
  );

  var _mathservice;

  beforeEach(inject((mathservice) => {
    _mathservice = mathservice;
  }));

  it('1 + 1 should equal 2', function(){
    var actual = _mathservice.addTwoNumbers(1,1);
    expect(actual).toEqual(2);
  });

  it('10 + 5 should equal 15', function(){
    var actual = _mathservice.addTwoNumbers(10,5);
    expect(actual).toEqual(15);
  });

  it('50 + 80 should equal 130', function(){
    var actual = _mathservice.addTwoNumbers(50,80);
    expect(actual).toEqual(130);
  });

});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angularjs-jest-example",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "description": "AngularJs with Jest example",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --coverage"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/curttimson/angularjs-jest-example.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/curttimson/angularjs-jest-example/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/curttimson/angularjs-jest-example#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.8.2",
    "jest": "^26.6.3"
  }
}
```

This is all code from an tutorial on how to test AngularJS with Jest that i use to try a few things.
I have a problem, that as soon as i add the .config([]) to the mathmodule in mathservice.js, i get these errors:

```
 [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=mathmodule&p1=Error%3A%20%5Bng%3Aareq%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%...
```

At first i had Providers in the .config so i thought i had to mock those providers somehow, but I get the same error when having an empty .config statement. Does anyone know why this happens?

[the repo i got my code from](https://github.com/curtistimson/angularjs-jest-example)